# Find the value of pi from the infinite series (pi=4-4/3+4/5-4/7+4/9-4/11…. ) using recursion in java

Tags: java, recursion

I have written multiple attempts to this problem, but I think this is the closest I could get. This solution makes the method recurse infinitely, because I don't have a base case, and I can't figure it out. The counter++ line is unreachable, and I can't get this to work, and I am very tired. This would be very easy with a loop, but recursion is kind of a new concept to me, and I would be thankful if someone helped me solve this.

```
public static double pi(int a, double b){
int counter=0;

if (counter %2==0){
    return a-(a/(pi(a,b+2)));
    counter++;
} else { 
    return a+(a/(pi(a,b+2)));
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: This is actually easier to code without recursion.  Is this just an exercise?

Comment: mostly the reason the above code doesn't work is not because the `counter++` line isn't reachable, but because even when you fix that you reset `counter` to zero in every call!  Oh, and I think the math is wrong, too...

Answer (score 0):

You could pass in another int, say `limit`, and add this code:

```
if (b > limit) {
    return a;
}
```

Or you could pass in some tolerance value:

```
if (pi(a,b+2) < tolerance) {
    return a;
}
```

Whenever you're working with recursion it's good to establish an exit strategy up front.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation that works.  Do not use it:

```
public static double term(double acc, int n, int r) {
    if (r-- > 0) {
        double sgn = (n % 4 == 1) ? +1.0 : -1.0;
        acc += sgn * 4.0 / n;
        n += 2;
        return term(acc, n, r);
    } else {
        return acc;
    }
}

public static double pi() {
    return term(0.0, 1, 1000);
}
```

The reason not to use it is that this particular infinite series is a particularly poor way of calculating π because it converges very slowly.  In the example above event after 1000 iterations are performed it's still only correct to 3 decimal places because the final calculated term is 4 / 1000.

Going much beyond 1000 iterations results in a stack overflow error with little improvement in the accuracy even though the `term` function is (I think) potentially tail recursive.